# Converting static site to Drupal 7 - How to set-up department sites?

Tags: migrations, multi-sites

I am new to Drupal.  We have a corporate site that is static html, has 13 departments.  The template for the department sites are very similar to the main corporate site.  The departments will not have a different DNS assigned to it, that is, the structure will be as so:

- main site URL:  www.mycorp.com
- department Site:  www.mycorp.com/hr

We would want the departments to update their own content. Each department has about 10 pages to maintain, but can grow. It is also important that all of the departments' content is  shared/accessed/searched by the main corporate site. Would Drupal 7 multisite set-up be recommended for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think multisite is not the optimal solution for you. With a multisite installation, you will end up with completely separate sites that have their own content, categories, users, settings, user files etc. etc. In my experience, that is often too much separation for a site like yours.

For instance: With multisite, if one person needs to get access to two or more departments, you need to create a user account for him in each site. He will also need to login in every site. Another example: With multisite, it's not easy to take content from a department site and promote it to the main home page.

In your case, I would look into a solution built with [Workbench](http://drupal.org/project/workbench) and [Workbench Access](http://drupal.org/project/workbench_access), or perhaps [Domain Access](http://drupal.org/project/domain). With those modules, you will end up with a system that is technically a single site, but where Drupal is configured to split the site into sections and control user permissions on a per-section basis.

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of ways to do this and other answers may expand upon your options.

I would suggest enabling Views module to select the content for each department's path.  You can also attach a field (using a taxonomy vocabulary) to each user to identify the department's they have access to.  The view will then allow you to limit who can see the contents on each departments view definition.

There is a quirk in the current Views filters that requires you to set up a relationship to content author before you can see users in the filters section.  If you have a problem seeing the users, ask a question on this site, and someone can guide you through the setup.

Comment: I'm wondering why this is the accepted answer now, because this is a very limited approach. The solution above only focuses on restricting the output side of things, and it's not even a secure way of doing that. I believe @Hjones mainly needs a way to allow departments to edit their own section of the site, but Views (even though it's a great module) does not do that.